# Как прибавить значение в mongodb?

Tags: база-данных, mongodb, mongoose

**Как добавить в документ коллекции `mongodb` значение, не перезаписывая полностью поле?**
Метод `insert`, насколько понял, вставляет новый документ в коллекцию, а `update` перезаписывает данные. Задача: нужно хранить список подключенных к некоторой странице сервера клиентов.
Если клиент покинет страницу, то удалить его из массива клиентов в документе `mongodb`. Как удалить тоже не знаю, тот же `update` лишь перезапишет соотв. поле.
**Как корректно хранить список подключенных клиентов?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правельно понял, то есть документ по типу:

```
 {
    "_id" : ObjectId(""),
    "Title" : "Sessions",
    "Users" : [ 
        {
            "Date" : "09/05/20017",
            "UserName" : "name",
            "UserId" : ObjectId("")
        }, 
        {
            "Date" : "09/05/20017",
            "UserName" : "name1",
            "UserId" : ObjectId("")
        }
    ]
}
```

Добавить нового `user` :

```
db./название коллекции/.update({ _id: /id вашего документа/}, {
            $addToSet: { "Users": {/ Объект с данными user/}}
        })
```

или

```
db./название коллекции/.update({ _id: /id вашего документа/}, {
            $push: { "Users": {/ Объект с данными user/}}
        })
```

Удалить нужного `user` :

```
db./название коллекции/.update({ _id: /id вашего документа/},
            { $pull: { "Users": { UserId: /id удаляймого/} } })
```

Comment: Спасибо..............      !